# Play framework (Java) can't find cache after deployment. "There is no cache plugin registered"

Tags: java, caching, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm having problems getting Play to use the cache after deploying to my server. The cache works fine in my development environment (Eclipse) but throws an exception on the target server. It states that there is no cache plugin registered.

[The documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/Migration22) says to add the cache as a dependency to the Build.scala file but that didn't work. `play dependencies` reports play-cache_2.10.jar and play-cache_2.10.jar as dependencies.

Message: *"There is no cache plugin registered. Make sure at least one CachePlugin implementation is enabled."*

Build.scala:

```
... 
val appDependencies = Seq(  
    javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean, cache  
)
```

(Play version 2.2.2)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register/enable the plugin as well by adding it as a dependency by adding a line like this to `config/play.plugins`:

```
500:play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin
```

(The number is a sort order so that you can prioritize between plugins in case they depend on each other)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. The file doesn't seem to be picked up by play. There must be some strange configuration problem.